# Запуск ещё одной копии приложения программно

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли как-то программно, в ответ на нажатие кнопки формы, открыть ещё одну копию приложения, как если просто открыть .exe-файл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

---

Это решение специфично для Windows Forms. Более общее решение — использовать рефлексию для нахождения пути:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase
```

Этот вызов вернёт URI-строку наподобие

```
file:///C:/Program Files/YourProgram/YourProgram.exe
```

которую можно скормить в `Process.Start`. Если вы всё же хотите путь с привычным синтаксисом, примените конструкцию

```
new Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath
```

которая вернёт обыкновенный адрес наподобие

```
C:\Program Files\YourProgram\YourProgram.exe
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33993/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------).